# How to format associative array

Tags: php, arrays, format, associative-array

I have this code:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);ini_set('display_errors', 1);

require 'config.php';

            $query = $_GET['q'];
            if ($query==null) {
                exit('No query');
            }

$sql = "SELECT title,uploader FROM `uploads_public` ";

        if($stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql)){
            // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
            $stmt->bindParam(":query", $query, PDO::PARAM_STR);




            // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
            if($stmt->execute()){
               echo "Your search $query has the following results(normal PDO:FETCH_ASSOC):<br>";
               $results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
               print_r($results);


              echo "Here are you <b>real</b> search results:<br>";
         } else{
                echo "Something went wrong. Please try again later. <br>"; print_r($stmt->errorInfo());
            }
                    // Close statement
        unset($stmt);
        unset($pdo);
        }





   else{
die("no input");
} 

require 'vendor/autoload.php';
$fuse = new \Fuse\Fuse(($results+= ["keys" => "title"]));
echo("var_dump returns:<br>");

print_r($results);
print_r($fuse->search(".$query."));
```

It is basically meant to get mysql data and turn it into something ***like*** this(i.e in this syntax):

```
[list] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [title] => Old Man's War
                    [author] => John Scalzi
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [title] => The Lock Artist
                    [author] => Steve Hamilton
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [title] => HTML5
                    [author] => Remy Sharp
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [title] => Right Ho Jeeves
                    [author] => P.D Woodhouse
                )

        )

)
```

But rather It outputs:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [title] => 1548457954
            [uploader] => hey
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [title] => 1548458360
            [uploader] => root
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [title] => first
            [uploader] => root
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [title] => first
            [uploader] => root
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [title] => first
            [uploader] => root
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [title] => first
            [uploader] => root
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [title] => first
            [uploader] => root
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [title] => first
            [uploader] => root
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [title] => first
            [uploader] => root
        )

    [9] => Array
        (
            [title] => first
            [uploader] => root
        )

    [10] => Array
        (
            [title] => first
            [uploader] => root
        )

    [11] => Array
        (
            [title] => RAD
            [uploader] => root
        )

    [12] => Array
        (
            [title] => RAD
            [uploader] => root
        )

    [13] => Array
        (
            [title] => GOOD
            [uploader] => root
        )

    [14] => Array
        (
            [title] => HAVE
            [uploader] => root
        )

    [15] => Array
        (
            [title] => rad
            [uploader] => dboss
        )

    [16] => Array
        (
            [title] => rad
            [uploader] => dboss
        )

    [17] => Array
        (
            [title] => new Image
            [uploader] => dboss
        )

    [18] => Array
        (
            [title] => My beautiful file
            [uploader] => root
        )

    [19] => Array
        (
            [title] => 
            [uploader] => root
        )

    [20] => Array
        (
            [title] => Apple
            [uploader] => root
        )

    [keys] => title
)
```

What do I extra  code do I need to add to make It format the way I want?
.........................................................................................................................................................................................................................................

Comment: It's giving you exactly what you asked for Title and Uploader. Maybe ask for Author and it will give it to you ... `SELECT title, author ........`

Comment: If you want those specific results, you should be making some _attempt_ to achieve them.  Right now, it is unclear why you would expect that result from your current code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `author` is actually the `uploader` then change the query to alias it:

```
SELECT title, uploader AS author FROM `uploads_public`
```

If it is an actual column then:

```
SELECT title, author FROM `uploads_public`
```

Second, to get the `list` array:

```
$results['list'] = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

`$results+= ["keys" => "title"]` is a mystery unless you can explain what it's supposed to do.  Probably just use `$results`.